# git: reset branch from detached state

Tags: git

I did this (on my production server):

```
$ git branch
* master
$ git fetch staging
$ git checkout staging/stage1
```

Now I want the `master` branch to point to HEAD which is a SHA-1 hash. I also want the `master` reflog updated.

how can I do that?

EDIT:

To clarify what I mean by "reflog": I want `$GIT_DIR/logs/refs/heads/master` to have one more line added to it when I'm done. That is, I want to change `master` branch, and then have `master@{1}` point to exactly where master branch just was. So yes, I am referring to something which is repo specific. I want to be able to undo this ref change somehow if I need to.

I would just do `echo .git/refs/remotes/staging/stage1 > .git/refs/heads/master` and that would change the master branch to exactly where I want it, but `.git/logs` folder wouldn't be updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git update-ref refs/heads/master HEAD` is the command I need.

I also apparently need to fully type out the branch names because it looks like update-ref isn't smart enough to "resolve" it's arguments. Meaning, typing "master" as an argument will have git create a branch at .git/master instead of knowing that I mean "refs/heads/master".

This will update the log...

```
If config parameter "core.logAllRefUpdates" is true or the file "$GIT_DIR/logs/<ref>" exists then git update-ref will append a line to the log file "$GIT_DIR/logs/<ref>"
```

(taken from http://csurs.csr.uky.edu/cgi-bin/man/man2html?1+git-update-ref)

Answer (score 1):

```
git update-ref HEAD master
```

This will make "master" point where your current HEAD is. I don't know what you mean by "want the `master` reflog updated" - if you want the `master` log updated, that will happen as a consequence of the ref change. The *reflog* is a per-repository thing, not tied to a particular branch.

Quoting from manpage of `git update-ref`:

```
   In general, using
       git update-ref HEAD "$head"
   should be a lot safer than doing
       echo "$head" > "$GIT_DIR/HEAD"
```

About updating the reflog:

> If config parameter "core.logAllRefUpdates" is true or the file
>   "$GIT_DIR/logs/" exists then git update-ref will append a line to
>   the log file "$GIT_DIR/logs/" (dereferencing all    symbolic refs
>   before creating the log name) describing the change in ref value.

Comment: @Jefromi I'm referring to the log of revisions behind the current HEAD. I have no idea what the asker was attempting to reference by saying "reflog", so I assume they've got a misconception about what they see when they type `git log`.

Comment: Okay. It's really best to avoid inventing terms, especially ones that are variations on existing ones, when talking to people who are clearly fuzzy on the details. Perhaps you could edit your answer?

Comment: @Jefromi That's not exactly an invented term - it's just a contracted form of "revision log". But I've edited the answer to just say "log".

Comment: Cool, thanks. I know where it came from, but, well, imagine a world where we have to explain the difference between revlog and reflog.

Comment: I clarified what I meant by "reflog", see edit.  Also, I may be misunderstanding the argument order for `update-ref`, but I want to check anyways: are you sure that you have the arguments in the correct order? won't what you have right now change the `HEAD` ref instead of the master ref?

Comment: @Thr4wn I've edited the answer. The arguments are in the correct order, and whether the reflog is updated depends on the value of a config setting.

Answer (score 0):

From your current state do:

```
git checkout master
git reset -hard HEAD@{1}
```

But it is not clear what you are trying and don't understand what you are talking about reflog